# is there a lo-dash method to check if two objects share specified keys?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two objects A and B. I want to know if they share the keys x and y.

I wrote this:

```
function sharesKeys(keys, objA, objB) {
    return _.every(keys, function (key) {
        return key in objA && key in objB;
    });
}
```

to be called as:

```
if (sharesKeys(['x', 'y'], cellA, cellB)) { ...
```

but want to know if I am missing a lo-dash method to do this directly.

Comment: No. Your function is fine to do this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated by @Bergi, you're fine to do that, because there's no such function in Lo-Dash.

As a suggestion, you could test if N objects share that keys, and not only 2!